# jQuery add a row in the middile of a table

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't the insertion after row 3 work?
Are there other ways I should be using?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Add Row</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

    $("document").ready(function() {
        //alert("document ready");

        $("#EditComp tr:first").after('<tr><td>This row added after first</td></tr>');
        $("#EditComp tr:last").after('<tr><td>This row added after last</td></tr>');

        $('#EdRow3 tr').after('<tr><td>This row added after 3</td></tr>');

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="EditComp">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="EdRow1"><td>Row 1</td></tr>
            <tr id="EdRow2"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
            <tr id="EdRow3"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
            <tr id="EdRow4"><td>Row 4</td></tr>
            <tr id="EdRow5"><td>Row 5</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't the insertion after row 3 work?
Are there other ways I should be using?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the tr after #EdRow3 in your javascript code.
Check the follwing code..

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Table Add Row</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">

    $("document").ready(function() {
        //alert("document ready");

        $("#EditComp tr:first").after('<tr><td>This row added after first</td></tr>');
        $("#EditComp tr:last").after('<tr><td>This row added after last</td></tr>');

        $('#EdRow3').after('<tr><td>This row added after 3</td></tr>');

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="EditComp">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="EdRow1"><td>Row 1</td></tr>
            <tr id="EdRow2"><td>Row 2</td></tr>
            <tr id="EdRow3"><td>Row 3</td></tr>
            <tr id="EdRow4"><td>Row 4</td></tr>
            <tr id="EdRow5"><td>Row 5</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#EdRow3 tr')` should be `$('#EdRow3')`.

Yours selects `tr`s which are descendants of `#EdRow3`.

`$('tr#EdRow3')` would also work, but having the `tr` there is unnecessary, as element `id`s are unique.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$('#EdRow3 tr').after('<tr><td>This row added after 3</td></tr>');
```

to this

```
$('tr#EdRow3').after('<tr><td>This row added after 3</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/j9G2t/)

Your selector was incorrect.

```
$('#EdRow3').after('<tr><td>This row added after 3</td></tr>');
```